# Keep track of completed Futures

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, scala-2.10

I'm spawning a large number (~100.000) http-request tasks as Futures in Scala. This takes a while, so I would like to be able to keep track of how many of those futures have successfully completed or failed by incrementing a global counter. I want, however, to avoid race conditions. Are there options in Scala to make an atomic counter? Or is there better way to go?

The code looks like this:

```
val futures = for(i <- 0 until nSteps) yield future {
    ...
    val content = blocking { ... http request ... }
    process(content)
}
Await.result(Future.sequence(futures),2 hours)
```

Comment: Have you thought about "why" your Futures may fail. What if you get all the replies back in a short window of time. Do you have the resources to handle ("process") your responses ? If not, your Futures may just timeout because of that ?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta, I don't think many fail. If they fail, it's very likely because the server didn't respond. I just want to keep track of the progress.

Comment: It may be that futures are not the thing you are looking for. Have you thought of an Actor ,amaging the calculations ? That would allow you to do it without blocking but would get you around the synch issue.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using the standard Java [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). You can increment it using the `incrementAndGet()` method, and obtain the current value via its `get()` method.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
...
val completed = new AtomicInteger()
val futures = for(i <- 0 until nSteps) yield future {
    ...
    val content = blocking { ... http request ... }
    process(content)
    completed.incrementAndGet()
}
Await.result(Future.sequence(futures),2 hours)
...
print("Completed: %d" format completed.get)
```

Comment: If you're running on Java 8, [LongAdder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) may be more efficient.

Comment: How would I construct an AtomicInteger in Scala? Sorry, I'm still very new to Scala.

Comment: import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger; val a = new AtomicInteger(); a.incrementAndGet

Comment: Oh yes, I should've included this in my answer. A stylistic remark:  while `a.incrementAndGet` is legal, `a.incrementAndGet()` should be preferred to emphasize its side-effect (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-0)